# Copy folder named today's date to AWS s3 using bash script and `date`

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Im trying to have part of my script copy an entire folder daily to AWS. No matter what I try, it seems to fail and tell me `[Errno 21] Is a directory:`
Script is super simple, but it will only copy (or sync) the contents of the folder and never the folder itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
today2=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
aws s3 sync /home/$today2 s3://testbucket/
```

Another script I use creates creates a folder with today's date and then pushes backups in to it. I want to move that day's folder to AWS. I've tried `--recursive` tried using both `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 sync` but neither of them seem to work.

If I was to just sync the root folder, it would copy over the folder that I needed, but I don't want all the other stuff in there... just today's folder.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: `/home/$today2/`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm underthinking this, but this, but why wouldn't `aws s3 sync /home/$today2 s3://testbucket/$today2` work?

Answer (score 1):

@Jamie Starke answer helped to solve my task with the Copy command

Works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
TODAYBKPDIR="$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")"
aws s3 cp --recursive /path/to/your/directory/"$TODAYBKPDIR" s3://your-bucket-name/"$TODAYBKPDIR"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, other way around trying to copy a file from S3 to local folder with date in the file name, need to be done everyday and in my sh file i had the below code and it worked perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
sudo aws s3 sync s3://<S3-PATH>/ /<my_local_folder>/A/ --exclude "*" --include "startup_sh.log."$today*

* is to copy all files created today.
```

hope this answer helps someone who needs both aws s3 and bash commands.